# Cannot install Sourcetree because oAuth redirection page does not load in localhost at port 34106

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, localhost, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Trying to install source tree in my Windows 10. They are asking for mandatory BitBucket account and after creating account when I proceed their `oAuth`, I found `state` and auth `code` are being sent like, `http://localhost:34106/?state=authenticated&code=CHabzvwrFjNAEzWYCD`. But `localhost` seems not running in my Windows and hence gage loading fails.

```
There was a temporary DNS error. Try refreshing the page.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
```

Anyone faced similar issue? What's the resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sourcetree seems to be using the [Loopback Interface Redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.3), which is a recommended [solution for Windows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#appendix-B.3).

Your error `INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND` seems to be DNS related, so I would first try if there is something wrong with resolving localhost to `127.0.0.1`. Try to `ping localhost` If it fails (which would be strange), you can add localhost to `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

If `localhost` is correcly resolved to `127.0.0.1`, your firewall may be the problem. I would try to stop if during the Sourcetree installation.

I have Sourcetree installed on my computer, but the installation went without problems, so I'm just writing what I would try to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Seems logical, I will have a try.